# Access is denied - Trusted internet site called from intranet with BASIC CORS Authentication - IE11 Compatibility - ExtJS

Tags: rest, api, extjs, internet-explorer-11, intranet

I am working on a project where am having to call REST API in internet from my intranet website. I am having to do this from client side(ExtJS) for various reasons. However this call requires CORS with basic authentication. This is working fine in chrome and firefox. The minimum version of IE that our users use is IE11. Also we can see from the rendered page source that IE9 compatibility is forced as below

`<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=9" />`

My question is, does the above tag disable the use of XMLHTTPRequest? Is that the reason why we are getting Access Is Denied error. We tried changing it to XDomainRequest sadly i found that it does not support Authorization headers to be added and it is not working.

Using developer tools we changed the mode to Edge, which is making the new call work but fails many existing JS code. Any suggestions on how i can proceed further

Comment: XMLHTTPRequest is supported in IE from IE 7. so if your site is loading in IE 9 document mode than also it should work. Access denied simply means you don't have right to access specific thing. It can be due to high level of security. Just for testing purpose, can you try to lower down the security settings for IE and make a test again to check whether it helps to fix the issue. If you post the full error message or screenshot of the error message than it will be helpful to know some more information about the issue.

Comment: sorry, i think i got it wrong. But as i understand CORS is not supported by IE9 and lower with xmlhttprequest.

Comment: I check the documentation and found that CORS has partial support for IE 8 to IE 10 but it supported in IE 11. So if possible for you than can you try to load your site in document mode IE 11? https://i.postimg.cc/qvKk0gYP/312.png Ref: https://caniuse.com/#feat=cors

Comment: could you just use jsonp proxy instead of json proxy?